# Nestjs cannot resolve circular dependency

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, nest

I am trying to write tests in NestJS with Jest. But when I import the module, I get this error.
note that

- at index 6 the service expects paramX.
- param X is part of module X
- this module X is imported in current Module (module that i am testing) as forwardRef(() => moduleX) and vice versa

can anyone suggest a workaround for this issue?

Test Module Code:

```
imports: [
    TestingModule,
    moduleA,
    WinstonModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => configService.getWinstonOptions(),
    }),
  ]
})
  .overrideGuard(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  .useValue(mockJWTGuard)
  .overrideProvider('REQUEST')
  .useValue({
    ip: '127.0.0.1',
    headers: {
      'x-original-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1',
    },
    user: {
      id: 1,
    },
  })
```

Error

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the serviceA (param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, ?, param8, param9, param9, param10, param11, REQUEST). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [6] is available in the RootTestModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
```